# How to extract the "coefficients" of a symbolic matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, symbolic-math, coefficients

Given a symbolic square matrix y (Matlab code: `syms y [n n] matrix;`), for a symbolic matrix of the form x=y+Ay+yB+CyD+EyF+... (where A, B, C, D, E, F... are numerical matrices), how can one separate the numerical matrices from x as matrices A, B, C, D, E, F... using Matlab?

Example:

```
syms y [3 3] matrix;
A=randi(2,3,3);
B=randi(2,3,3);
C=randi(2,3,3);
D=randi(2,3,3);
x=y+A*y+y*B+C*y*D
```

Run the code yields:

```
y*symmatrix([2,1,1;2,1,1;1,1,1]) + symmatrix([2,2,1;1,2,2;2,2,2])*y + symmatrix([1,1,2;1,1,1;1,2,2])*y*symmatrix([2,2,2;2,2,1;1,1,1]) + y
```

My question is: given the equation x=f(y), like above, how do I obtain all of the matrices where y is multiplied by left and right?

I looked up the functions in the Symbolic Math Toolbox and Googled related questions, unfortunately all I could find was about the coefficients of symbolic polynomials or other expressions, and the "coefficients" of symbolic matrices were hard to find relevant answers.

Comment: I'm unaware of any kind easy way to do this. `symmatrix` objects are fairly new to Matlab (since R2021a) and there doesn't seem to be many of the same features one has access to with vanilla `sym` objects. I'd suggest you consider filing a [service request](https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html?s_tid=hc_trail) with The MathWorks on this or try [their own forums](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/index/?s_tid=gn_mlc_an).

Comment: Perhaps a partial answer: I think you can convert a `symmatrix` object using `z=symmatrix2sym(x)`. Then you can use `children(z, 1)` or `children(z(1))` to get some of the coefficients. You can combine this with `coeffs`. I don't know if this would be useful: you might also consider evaluate the matrix at the identity (i.e. `subs(x, y, eye(3))` and using that in this calculation`. Finally, when you talk about the things you have already tried - what exactly did you try and what were the results?

Comment: To @magnesium: Thanks to your suggestion, I really didn't clarify my current situation: the problem I was dealing with with MATLAB was too large, the memory would be low if I used a matrix of type sym, or the run time would be unbearable.